# how to pass check box id in materialize bridge

Tags: typescript, materialize

i have the following checkbox that i populate

ts

```
daysofWeek = [
        { id: 0, name: 'Sunday' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Monday' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Tuesday' },
    ];

    days = [];
```

html

```
<div repeat.for="day of daysofWeek">
                    <md-checkbox checked.bind="days" model.bind="day">${day.name}</md-checkbox>
                
                    <ul>
                        <li repeat.for="day of days">${day.id}</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
```

in my ts i am trying to get the id back if its checked but its coming back as

```
0:{id:0,name:sunday}
1:{id:1,name:monday}
```

submit() {

```
     let daysofweek = this.days; // gets returned here 0:{id:0,name:sunday}1:{id:1,name:monday}

     if (this.repeat === true) {
         this.Instance({
        daysOfWeek: daysofweek, //how do i pass in here [0,1]
 });}
```

i tried changing the html to

```
<md-checkbox checked.bind="days" model.bind="day.id">${day.name}</md-checkbox>
```

but it doesnt work

i also tried in ts

```
let daysofweek = this.days.id;
```

but it gives me an error that it cant find the name id

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out incase anyone else is having the same problem,i did the following

```
 let daysofweek = this.days.map(x => x.id);
```